# Not Able to create APK through Ant , not able to give external jar path with different folder except libs

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant, jar

I am stuck in a weird situation; I have two projects I need to generate apk through the ant command line. 
In a Library project I have multiple jars which have same classes & packages.
If I pull all jars in **libs folder** then I am getting **multiple dex jar error** from both (eclipse and ant) but in eclipse I am able to create apk. 
I did remove duplicate jars in other **jar folder** from **libs** & add as external jars.
But in ANT it gives **no symbol found errors;**. 
According to requirement I need to execute my projects with ant. 
I also try remove duplicate packages from jars but still no success.
I simply use following commands:

```
 android.bat update lib-project --target android-21 --path ../LibraryProject
 android.bat update project --target android-21 --path . --name projectName --library ../LibraryProject --subprojects
```

I have searched a lot. I have seen that we need to put all jars in **libs** in ant but according to my situation I need to put two jars as external and other in **libs folder** .Please help

Comment: *Why* do you need to use Ant instead of Gradle?

Comment: @chrylis: Because it's an large old project in eclipse. We didn't port into gradle till now . & client don't have eclipse & studio . Thats why